# How to change color of new cmd window (together with a custom prompt) created via running a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I already know how to create a new cmd window from a batch script with custom color, and a new cmd window with a custom prompt. However am wanting to find a way of combining the two together...

Here is what I have in my batch file to create a new cmd window with customised prompt (in this case, the customised prompt is the windows version details):

```
start cmd /k "prompt $v"
```

... And this is what I'm doing to create a new cmd window with customised color:

```
start cmd /k "color 42"
```

I've tried the following to combine the two, but none of them work:

```
start cmd /k "color 42" /k "prompt $v"

start cmd /k"color 42" "prompt $v"
```

If anyone can help point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Been searching via Google and other forums but after spending over an hour on a fruitless search I thought I'd ask a question here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is the operator that will concatenate multiple commands on one line: `&`.

```
start cmd /k "color 42&prompt $v"
```

This operator works in all situations, not just within the command string for the CMD command. There are a few concatenation operators with different behavior:

- `&` - Always executes the next command
- `&&` - Only executes the next command if the prior command was successful (ERRORLEVEL=0)
- `||` - Only executes the next command if the prior command failed (ERRORLEVEL<>0)

Comment: Ahhh so that's what I was missing... thanks heaps :). This will definitely come in handy

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
start cmd /k"color 42; prompt $v"
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Maksym, although in the new cmd window I get a whole lot of information about setting the color foreground and background. I tried *start cmd /k "color 42; prompt $v"* and *start cmd /k "color 42"; "prompt $v"* and they didn't work either. I know I could create another batch file that has the color and prompt settings built in, but I have been specifically told to create a new command window with custom text and background color and custom prompt...

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here, but note that `cmd /t:fg` will [set the colors just like the `color` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), so you could also run

```
start cmd /t:42 /k "prompt $v"
```