# Open Batch file with custom color VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I'm trying to open batch files in a custom coloured cmd window by doing this:

```
Public Class MyUtilities
    Shared Sub RunCommandCom(command As String, arguments As String, permanent As Boolean)
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        pi.Arguments = " " + If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        p.StartInfo = pi
        p.Start()
    End Sub
End Class

       'Inside button click event
        Dim OpenCMD
        OpenCMD = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
        OpenCMD.run("cmd.exe & color 0e & " & My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\test.bat " & "VARIABLE", vbNormalFocus)
```

However, it keeps saying that the file could not be found, It works perfectly when I remove the `"cmd.exe & color 0e & "` from the start. As I'm working with a host of different batch files and do not want to change the color inside the batch file itself, how can I change it just so that it's a certain color when ran? -- The batch files are ran by a number of different programs, hence why I dont want to change the color of the actual batch file itself, only when ran from my program... I'm unable to make copies of the original file as well.

Your advice/corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of new cmd window (together with a custom prompt) created via running a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061961/how-to-change-color-of-new-cmd-window-together-with-a-custom-prompt-created-vi)

Comment: But I'm trying to use the & symbol to link the multiple commands :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not using `RunCommandCom` in the button click event. You just need to:

```
Dim cmd As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "test.bat")
RunCommandCom("color 0e & " & cmd, "VARIABLE", False)
```

Using [`IO.Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) takes care of path delimiters ("\" in this case) for you.

(Tested as working.)